# Can someone get late?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Which sentence is grammatically correct ?

**I am getting late.**

**It's getting late for me.**

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it would be a better ELL question if you took the time to tell us where you found these sentences, and why you're asking. I can't tell if you are trying to write something on your own and struggling to figure out which one is correct, or if you're just getting some help on a homework problem. (Either one is okay, but my answer might change depending on what you are trying to learn.)

Answer (score 1):

"**I am getting late**" is understood but not the common way people say it. The common way is "**I am running late**".

"**It is getting late**" is used to say that time is passing and especially that evening or late evening is coming. "**It is getting late for me**" means that "*by my standards or needs it's getting late*". This means that "*for someone else it might not be getting late just yet but for me it already is*".

Comment: Actually `It's getting late for me` is idiomatic. I would use that if we are out somewhere and I want to go home.

Comment: @mplungjan Maybe, I'm non-native, I feel it sounds like "*For me (in my way) it is getting late*" - not for everyone else maybe.

Comment: I know - you are Russian :) - have a look https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22getting+late+for+me%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=4qw7WsruHc3CwQLJ5bbgAQ

Comment: Native US English speaker here: *It's getting late* is, as you say, the standard way of saying that the hour is late, but adding **for me** adds the sense that it is late *by my standards or needs*.

Comment: @stangdon oh, that's how it works. Thnx.

Comment: So can I come to the conclusion that ' I am getting late '  is wrong?

Comment: @user271640 Not idiomatic but not wrong.